# printing a variable into a div

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I am atempting to build a chatroom with NodeJS and Socket.io and I have gotten so far as to get the users input and send it to the Node server but that's all I want to be able to display it up in a `div`

Client-side script

```
var socket = io();

$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // gets the value from the message text feild and sets it as the message var
  var message = {
    text: $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').val()
  }
  if (message.text.trim().length !== 0) {
    socket.emit('chat-message', message);
  }
  $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').focus();
  document.getElementById('chat-box-div-txtinpt').value='';
});
```

Server-side script

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconected');
  });
  socket.on('chat-message', function (message) {
    console.log('message: ' + message.text);
  });
});
```

Here is the [site](http://billischill.ddns.net:3000)

Comment: your server js is hard to see, please edit

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is....you are getting the input from your text area (or text box) and sending it to the server....are you trying to write the response from the server to a div?

Comment: the server should send back the message to client, not ``console.log`` in ``socket.on('chat-message')...``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're using jQuery, so for this line: `document.getElementById('chat-box-div-txtinpt').value='';` you could just do `$('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').val('');`

to answer your question: you could just do `$('#chatlog-display-div').append(message.text)`

Your code would end up looking something like this

```
 $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        //gets the value from the message text feild and sets it as the message var
    var message = {
        text : $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').val()
    }
    if (message.text.trim().length !== 0) {
      socket.emit('chat-message', message);

      //append the message to the chatlog-display-div
      $('#chatlog-display-div').append(message.text);
    }
    //clear the value of the txtinput after you focus it.
    $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').focus().val('');
});
```

please  mark as accepted answer if you feel this adequately solves the issue.

Comment: thank you that worked great i have another question is this practical for making a chatroom network you think?

Comment: nevermind i have found that no one else can see it exept for one users

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: I'm not familiar with the workings of socket.io. You should ask another question on StackOverflow pertaining to that. Here is a tutorial from socket.io pertaining to chat. http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: also, you'll want to sanitize the chat input. right now, you can type in something like `<script>alert('hello');</script>` and it will execute...huge problem.

Answer (score 0):

To send messages to everyone from the server use `emit()` from `io`

**on server**

```
socket.on('chat-message', function (message) {
   console.log('message : ' + message.text);
   io.emit("chat-message",message);
});
```

**on client**

```
socket.on('chat-message',function(message){
   //add message to the chat window
});
```

If you do not want the person sending the message to get the `chat-message` emit then use `broadcast.emit()` from the `socket` that sent it

```
//server
socket.on('chat-message', function (message) {
   console.log('message : ' + message.text);
   //excludes "socket" from getting the emit
   socket.broadcast.emit("chat-message",message);
});
```

To actually put the message in the div just use any of jQuery's various methods [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html)/[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text)/[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append)

```
//client
socket.on('chat-message', function (message) {
   jQuery(".chat-window").append('<div>'+message.text+'</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simple  .append the text to "chatlog-display-div" with a templet if you use ES6 could be something like

> $('form').submit(function(e) {
>           e.preventDefault();

```
        //gets the value from the message text feild and sets it as the message var
    var message = {
        text : $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').val()
    }
    if (message.text.trim().length !== 0) {
      socket.emit('chat-message', message);
      document.getElementById('chatlog-display-div').append('<divclass="message-style" > ${message.text}</div>')
    }
    $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').focus();
        document.getElementById('chat-box-div-txtinpt').value='';
});
```